# Evaluate by polynomial expansion the following integral with an error less than 0.000001

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

My work till now:

$\int_0^{0.2} \frac{1}{1+x^5} dx=\int_0^{0.2}(1+x^5)^{-1} dx$

$(1+x)^n=1+nx+ \frac{n(n-1)x^2}{2}...$

$\int_0^{0.2} \bigl( 1+(-1)x^5+ \frac{(-1)(-2)x^{10}}{2}- \frac{1(-2)(-3)x^{15}}{3!}+...\bigr)dx$

Now, I could integrate the above series but how can I find the result within that error?

Any tip/help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the approximation works well: since
$$1+x^{15}=(1+x^5)(1-x^5+x^{10})$$
it follows that for any $x\in [0,1]$
$$\frac{1}{1+x^5}=1-x^5+x^{10}-\frac{x^{15}}{1+x^5}.$$
Hence
$$\begin{align}
\left|\int_{0}^{0.2}\frac{1}{1+x^5}\,dx-\int_{0}^{0.2}(1-x^5+x^{10})\,dx\right|&\leq\int_{0}^{0.2} \frac{x^{15}}{1+x^5}\,dx\\
&\leq \int_{0}^{0.2} x^{15}\,dx=\frac{(0.2)^{16}}{16}<10^{-12}.
\end{align}$$
Note that
$$\int_{0}^{0.2}\frac{1}{1+x^5}\,dx
\approx 0.199989335194742$$
and
$$\int_{0}^{0.2}(1-x^5+x^{10})\,dx\approx 0.1999893351951515.$$

P.S. Actually for an error less that $0.000001=10^{-6}$ you may consider less terms:
$$\frac{1}{1+x^5}=1-x^5+\frac{x^{10}}{1+x^5}.$$

Answer (score 0):

By the alternating series error estimate, if $x \geq 0$ then $\frac{1}{1+x^5}$ is between $\sum_{n=0}^N (-1)^n (x^5)^n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{N+1} (-1)^n (x^5)^n$ for any nonnegative integer $N$. Therefore the error in approximating $\int_0^{0.2} \frac{1}{1+x^5} dx$ by $\int_0^{0.2} \sum_{n=0}^N (-1)^n (x^5)^n dx$ is no more than $\int_0^{0.2} x^{5(N+1)} dx = \frac{0.2^{5N+5}}{5N+5}$.

Of course this method doesn't work when the geometric series isn't alternating, in that situation you are better off with $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^N x^n + \frac{x^{N+1}}{1-x}$ which doesn't care about the sign of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

*Just for your curiosity*

It could be interesting to consider the general problem of
$$I_n=\int_0^{\frac 1n} \frac {dx}{1+x^n}=\sum_{k=0}^p  \frac{(-1)^k}{(k n+1)\, n^{(kn+1)}}+\sum_{k=p+1}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^k}{(k n+1)\, n^{(kn+1)}}$$ and you want to know (without systematic testing) the value of $p$ such that
$$R_p= \frac{1}{((p+1) n+1)\, n^{((p+1)n+1)}} \leq \epsilon\implies ((p+1) n+1)\, n^{((p+1)n+1)}\geq \frac 1 \epsilon$$
The solution is given is terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
$$p_*=\frac{W\left(\frac{\log (n)}{\epsilon }\right)}{n \log (n)}-\frac{1}{n}-1$$ and, as usual, you will need to use $p=\lceil p_* \rceil$.

For you specific case $n=5$ and $\epsilon=10^{-6}$, this would give $p_*=0.269019$ so $p=1$. Checking
$$R_1=\frac{1}{537109375}=1.86\times 10^{-9} \implies OK$$

Suppose now that we want $\epsilon=10^{-100}$, this would give $p_*=26.7995$ so $p=27$. Checking
$$R_{26}=6.41\times 10^{-98}  > 10^{-100} \qquad \text{while} \qquad R_{27}=1.98\times 10^{-101}  < 10^{-100} $$

If you cannot use Lambert function, since its argument is large, you can easily approximate its value using the expansion given in the linked page
$$W(t)\approx L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{L_2(L_2-2)}{2L_1^2}+\frac{L_2(2L_2^2-9L_2+6)}{6L_1^3}+\cdots$$ where $L_1=\log(t)$ and $L_2=\log(L_1)$ .

Comment: Didn't know what the Lambert function was. Gonna check it out later, but looks like it will take some time to get used to applying it. Still looks pretty clean and not too hard. Thanks for the response!